# Is Google Dialogflow available in Hungarian?

Tags: dialogflow-es

Is Dialogflow available in Hungarian ?

It is not a langage available in the official list in Dialogflow when you try to choose a langage.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As per https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/language, Hungarian is not mentioned as the supported languages of Dialogflow. However, Dialogflow should be able to perform the same NLP processes on Hungarian as well. Just that the semantic embedding used within Dialogflow might not give a good result. Syntactical similarity should still work. 
It all depends on the training phrases available for the intent.

My Experiment:
I tested a sample agent with "Szia hogy vagytok" (Assuming it means 'Hi How are you') as a training phrase of Welcome Intent and passed another utterance in test console: 'Szia'. It correctly classified the Welcome Intent.

Answer (score 0):

Hungarian is in supported language list now.

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/language